# Maximum time of Extract-Min - Fibonacci heap

Tags: algorithm, time, fibonacci-heap

What is the actual maximum time of executing `extract-min` on `n`-element Fibonacci heap?

Is it `O(D(n) + t(H))`, where `D(n) = lg*n` is the maximum degree of a node in n-element heap and `t(H) = O(n)` is a number of roots in heap H?

Does this mean that answer for question above is actually `O(n) = Theta(n)`? If no, please correct my thinking and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct -- the maximum time complexity of a single call to `deleteMin` is `O(n)`. The lower `O(logn)` bound on the operation is its amortized time complexity, and is the same between the best case and the worst case.

Comment: So the actual maximum time would be ``O(n)``. Can't there be any worse case? :)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking there. The worst situation for `deleteMin` is a heap with `n` roots, and that is processed in `O(n)` time.